# Targeting specific selector/top-margin

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this html

```
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title">...</h1>  
        <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="products-filters"></div>
</header>

<ul class="products columns-4 ">
        <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

And I need to target this specific ul to give it a different top margin than is set in the theme's css. The theme is adding

```
.woocommerce .products ul, .woocommerce ul.products{
        margin-top:2rem
}
```

I only need to apply a different top margin if the ul is following the products header, so I tried

```
.woocommerce-products-header + ul.products{
        margin-top:4rem
}
```

but this is not working. How can I give the ul a different top margin if it is directly following the products header?

Comment: try `header.woocommerce-products-header + ul.products`

Comment: no, still not working.